# C++ append to string and write to file

Tags: c++, string, file-io, file

Why does the following code not work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string data;
    int i=0;

    while(i <= 5){
      i++;
      data += i;
      data += "\n";
    }

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("data.txt");
    myfile << data;
    myfile.close();
}
```

It ***should*** append a **number** then **newline** and write it to a file **(that doesn't yet exist)**.

The file should look like this...

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Well, what do you get out of it so far?

Comment: The program will not compile. Where is main()?

Comment: `<stdio.h>` should be `<iostream>`, `<string.h>` should be `<string>`, and `<stdlib.h>` should be `<cstdlib>`.  And if you're going by a book, you need a new one. :)  Try Accelerated C++, and see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why do you not use `operator<<`?

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("data.txt");
for ( int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i )
  myfile << i << "\n";
myfile.close();
```

Comment: +1: also: if the intermediate string representation is important, use a stringstream in the place of the ofstream to have access to the string representation.

Comment: +1 This is the most correct answer, unless there is a reason to build the string (i.e. Manipulations done before tossing it in the file) then there is no reason for it to be there.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues with your code.  First of all, you're `#include`-ing several deprecated headers, including `<stdio.h>` which should be `<iostream>`, `<string.h>` which should be `<string>`, and `<stdlib.h>` which should be `<cstdlib>`.

As for your specific question, it is doing exactly what you asked it to do.  Problem is, you didn't ask it to do what you *wanted* it to do.  In your code `data += i;` you are saying "append the binary value `i` to this `string`" which your code dutifully does.  If you open your resulting text file in a binary-capable text editor, you'll find it is the binary data you inserted.

What you wanted to do was convert the integers to their string representations, and append that to the text file.  A simple way do this in a C++ish way is to use `stringstream`, as so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i=0;

        stringstream ss;
    while(i <= 5){
      i++;
            ss << i << endl;
    }

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("data.txt");
    myfile << ss.str();
    myfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that i see is that you are building off of the string data by adding integers to it.
What you actually want is the character version of the integer which would require something like this:

```
while(i <= 5){
  i++;
  data += char(i+48);
  data += "\n";
}
```

What this does is add the offset (48) from decimal representation to the [ASCII](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.cs.utk.edu/~pham/ascii_table.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.cs.utk.edu/~pham/ascii.html&h=475&w=715&sz=142&tbnid=fHeK-W8VD8qXUM:&tbnh=93&tbnw=140&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dascii%2Btable&zoom=1&hl=&usg=__tcacDXl2zZHS9twZkw4SjIP4TTU=&sa=X&ei=8vNzTNKvH4L68Aa0u9CGCQ&ved=0CCYQ9QEwAw) representation of the number.
**EDIT:** Tested this, depending if you want to print up to 6 or not you're also gonna wanna replace the `while(i <= 5)` with a `while(i < 5)` due to the way you set up the inside of the while loop.

Comment: IMHO, the assignment would read better as `data += '0' + i;`.  In this manner there is no need for the `char` cast, as the variable `i` is converted by the the compiler.

Comment: Works very well, that was simple enough

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it is better to read that way, however i believe seeing the literal `i+48` will better express the nature of the conversion to the OP.

Comment: @Mark As long as you understand what it's doing, you can write it whatever way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that operator+=(int) is defined for std::string, so the line `data += i;` would, if it compiles at all, be translates as:

```
 data += (char) i;
```

Let's use actual chars here:

```
char i='0';   

while(i <= '5'){   
  i++;   
  data += i;   
  data += "\n";   
}
```

Furthermore, you are including `<string.h>` which is the C run-time library for strings (string here being arrays of tiny integers); What you actually need to include is `<string>` which is the C++ library for std::string.  As far as I can tell, you do not need stdio.h, stdlib.h or string.h at all.

Comment: Yes i fixed in noticed that and fixed <string.h> to <string>

Comment: I need stdio.h, stdlib.h or string.h bbecause that's a snippet of a bigger function :P

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also use sprintf as:

```
    char temp[10]; // assuming your string rep of the number won't take >9 char.

    while(i <= MAX){
            i++;
            sprintf(temp,"%d",i);
            data += temp;
            data += "\n";
    }
```